# SQLite: TypeError: query() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm a few months into seriously learning Python and I am trying to separate out my sqlite related functions from my main script however I'm having trouble passing the variables from the main script to the database module.

I have a main script which requests two inputs and passed them to the SELECT query function...

**MAIN SCRIPT**

```
from db_manage import inv_enq

def main():
    ord_numb = input('Enter Order Number > ')
    part_numb = input('Enter Part Number > ')
    inv_enq(ord_numb, part_numb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is linked to my database management script which has a class containing a the necessary to create, query and close an sqlite connection and the function containing the 'inv_enq' query I am trying to run.

**DB SCRIPT**

```
import sqlite3

class DbManager(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, arg):
        self.cur.execute(arg)
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.cur

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()


def inv_enq(ord_numb, part_numb):
    dbmgr = DbManager("tracker.db")
    for row in dbmgr.query("""SELECT * FROM inv_arch WHERE ord_num == (?) AND part_num == (?)""", (ord_numb, part_numb,)):
        print(row)
```

My problem occurs when I run the main script. Having passed the order number and part numbers in, I get the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...mainscript.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "...mainscript.py", line 10, in main
    inv_enq(ord_numb, part_numb)
  File "...db_manage.py", line 24, in inv_enq
    for row in dbmgr.query("""SELECT * FROM inv_arch WHERE ord_num == (?) AND part_num == (?)""", part_numb, ord_numb):
TypeError: query() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I'm confused as I believe I'm only passing two arguments but the error says 4. Some of my online reading into this problem lead to *syntactic sugar* but none has really helped me work out where I'm going wrong.

Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the code shown in the error does not match the code in the question; in the question you wrap the two parameters to be interpolated in a tuple, but that is not present in the traceback.

Secondly, your `query` method only takes one argument (apart from `self`). But you need to pass two: the query, and the arguments. You should define the method like this:

```
def query(self, query, args):
    self.cur.execute(query, args)
```

(And no, this has nothing whatsoever to do with syntactic sugar; I'm not sure what gave you the idea that it does.)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. As far as point 1 is concerned, my apologies, I made a couple of changes to hide private information and this has screwed up the code. Stupid I realise and noted for future questions. Point 2 - Being honest I'm still learning and I know guys on here like people to do their own research first. Strangely, many articles with similar error messages to mine had detail relating to syntactic sugar but thanks for ruling it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Culprit is this line:

```
for row in dbmgr.query("""SELECT * FROM inv_arch WHERE ord_num == (?) AND part_num == (?)""", part_numb, ord_numb)
```

1st argument is `self`

2nd is `"""SELECT * FROM inv_arch WHERE ord_num == (?) AND part_num == (?)"""`

if looking at code:

3rd argument  `('part_numb', 'ord_numb')`

or if looking at traceback:

3rd is `part_numb`

4th is `ord_numb`

as you see here, query only takes 2. `self` and `arg`

```
def query(self, arg):
    self.cur.execute(arg)
    self.conn.commit()
    return self.cur
```

`self` is never explicitly entered (technically its the object you created itself, in this case `dbmgr`)

From looking at your code it looks like you maybe wanted to insert ord_numb and part_numb into the SELECT statement in place of the (?)s

In that case then do something like this:

```
select_statement = """SELECT * FROM inv_arch WHERE ord_num == {} AND part_num == {}""".format(ord_numb, partnumb)
dbmgr.query(select_statement)
```

Comment: I was in a similar situation, this answer solved the problem. +1